# react material-table export render columns doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I'm using material-table and i need to export a table, but the rendered columns doesn't appear in the exported file and the others yes it does,here is a part of my code:

```
             {inputs.invoices.length  ? <MaterialTable 
                    columns={[
                      { title: '#',export: true, render: (invoice) => {
                        return `${invoice.prefix}-${invoice.invoiceNumber}`;
                      }},
                      { title: 'value',export: true, field: 'value' , type: 'currency'},
                      { title: 'status',export: true, render: (invoice) => {
                        var invoiceStatus = invoice.idInvoiceStatus;
                        return (invoiceStatus.name ? ' ' + invoiceStatus.name : '');
                      }},
                      { title: 'balance',export: true, field: 'balance' , type: 'currency'},
                      { title: 'date',export: true, field: 'dateCreated' , type: 'datetime'}
                    ]}
                    data={inputs.invoices}
                    title="Invoices List"
                    options={{
                      exportButton: true,
                      filter: true,
                      filterList: inputs.invoices,
                      headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: '#01579b',
                        color: '#FFF',
                        zIndex: '0'
                      }
                    }}
                  /> : null }
```

There is a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your example doesn't work because export functionality takes into consideration `data`  and `columns`. Whatever you do during column custom rendering shouldn't affect the data the table is working with. You can check an example of this definition on [Overriding Export Function Example](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/export).

So, depending on the context you are working on (data size, amount of columns, how many custom renderings, etc) I would consider two options:

- Add extra columns to your columns definition ( ofcourse it means also
  expanding your data definition) including those new calculated
  values, and then work with columns props definition to set the ones
  you choose as `hidden`, and define the boolean prop `export` in each
  case yoou need.

*or*

- Perfom this transformations to your data model during the export
  function. You could achieve that by providing a custom export
  function as susgested on the link to the ofitial docs above. Here is
  the code of the [defaultExportCsv](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/master/src/components/m-table-toolbar.js#L58) function that may come handy:

  ```
   defaultExportCsv = () => {
     const [columns, data] = this.getTableData();

     let fileName = this.props.title || "data";
     if (this.props.exportFileName) {
       fileName =
       typeof this.props.exportFileName === "function"
         ? this.props.exportFileName()
         : this.props.exportFileName;
     }

   const builder = new CsvBuilder(fileName + ".csv");
     builder
       .setDelimeter(this.props.exportDelimiter)
       .setColumns(columns.map((columnDef) => columnDef.title))
       .addRows(data)
       .exportFile();
   };
  ```

Hope that works for you!